# How to convert a D7 db_query object to string?

Tags: 7

I am trying to perform the following:

```
$office_ids = db_query('SELECT OFFICE_ID FROM sage.OFFICE');
foreach($office_ids as $office) {
  ...
  $path = 'office-' . (string)$office;
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in main() (line 31 of /var/www/drupal7/create_nodes_office.php).
```

How can I cast an object returned by 'db_query' into a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any benefit to doing that, are you sure you're not trying to get the `OFFICE_ID` value like this?:

```
$office_ids = db_query('SELECT OFFICE_ID FROM sage.OFFICE');
foreach($office_ids as $office) {
  ...
  // Depending on your database settings this might actually be lower case, i.e. $office->office_id
  $path = 'office-' . $office->OFFICE_ID;
}
```

Comment: thanks clive, that works. could you please explain how that works? i thought after you 'db_query' you already have the individual office ids, why do i need to $office->office_id again?

Comment: `db_query()` is a query resource which you iterate over, if you want it to return a single string you would use `$query->fetchField()`, if you wanted an array of values for a query that only fetches one column you would use `$query->fetchCol()`, and so on. There's a wealth of examples and thorough explanations over at the [Database API documentation](http://drupal.org/developing/api/database) if you really want to know how it works :)